# Cannot update during existing state

Tags: react-native

Index.js
I try do launch screen.

```
export default class LaunchScreen extends Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state= {
    loaded:false
    }
}

    componentWillMount(){
        Thread.load(v => this.setState({loaded:true}));
    }

render(){
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
            {this.state.loaded ? navigate("Form")
            :
            <View style={styles.imageContent}>
            <Image style={styles.image}
            source={require('../images/launch_icon.png')}/>
            </View>
            }
         </View>
        )}}


export default class thread{
static load(cb){
    setTimeout(cb,3000);

}
```

}

when I use these codes I get the warning "can not update during an existing state transition". How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to navigate inside a return, try to change your render code to this:

```
 render(){
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    if(this.state.loaded) navigate("Form")

    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>

            <View style={styles.imageContent}>
            <Image style={styles.image}
            source={require('../images/launch_icon.png')}/>
            </View>

         </View>
        )
}
```

EDIT: But you should probably do the navigation part inside a shouldComponentUpdate() checking if the nextState.loaded is different from your this.state.loaded and is true, like:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
    if((nextState.loaded!=this.state.loaded)&&nextState.loaded){
         navigate("Form")
         return true
    }
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple problems, but I don't think these are your main problems.

- You can only have one default export, so if both classes are actually in a single file, remove the "default" from the thread class.
- Pretty sure all class names must begin with a capital letter in React, so change "thread" to "Thread"

But I think your actual problem is that you're calling `navigate('Form')` directly from within the render. Try adding a `handleNavigation` class method and calling `this.handleNavigation` there instead. So you'd be left with something like this...

```
export default class LaunchScreen extends Component {
  state = {
    loaded: false
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    Thread.load( () => this.setState({loaded: true}));
  }

  handleNavigation = () => {
    this.props.navigation('Form');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {
          this.state.loaded 
            ? this.handleNavigation
            : <View style={styles.imageContent}>
                <Image style={styles.image}
                source={require('../images/launch_icon.png')}/>
              </View>
        }
     </View>
    );
  }
}

export class Thread {
  static load(cb){
      setTimeout(cb,3000);

  }
}
```